# Can I use loki ObjectLevelLockable in c++0x template

Tags: c++, templates, c++-loki

I want to create a thread safe fifo list using Loki library, but I can't create a guard because I'm using gcc 4.3 and it doesn't support alias templates:

```
....
template <typename T> MyFIFO: public ObjectLevelLockable<MyFIFO<T>>{
....
typedef MyFIFO<T>::Lock MyLock;
....
void some_function(const T& some_variable_name)
{
MyLock _lock(*this);//like in "Modern c++ Design p268"
....some code...
}
```

Any ideas... without installing gcc 4.7?

Comment: What is the problem with installing a compiler that is not ancient?

Comment: @PlasmaHH not the owner of the target system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Hmm! I was using loki, because it usually also works with ancient compilers (because it's being a bit ancient as well meanwhile).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typename MyFIFO<T>::Lock` is a dependent name, so you need a `typename` here:

```
typedef typename MyFIFO<T>::Lock MyLock;
        ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Great thank you, but now I get a call member without object... I think it has some more broken code.

Comment: I get it on _lock(*this).. I copied(by hand) the Loki lib, the multithread part, so might have missed something.